# Symfony3 : on delete cascade with 3 levels don't work (2 entities)

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, associations, symfony, cascading-deletes

I have this structure :

```
Root Level
-- Level 1         id : 1100    --> trying to delete this level
---- Level 1.1     id : 1101
------ product 1
------ product 2
```

I want to delete Level 1 what will cascade delete Level 1.1 and its 2 children.

I have an integrity constraint violation when I do :

```
$em->remove($level);
$em->flush();
```

`$level` represents **Level 1**.

> An exception occurred while executing `DELETE FROM level WHERE id = ?` with params [1100]
>
> **Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails** (mydb.product, CONSTRAINT my_constraint FOREIGN KEY (Level_ID) REFERENCES level (id))

This error seems to be on "product" table.

My entities :

```
class Level
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeParent
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Level", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Level", mappedBy="parent")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"lft" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="level", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"order" = "ASC"})
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $products;
}
```

This entity is construct according to [Tree extension for Doctrine2](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#including-extension)

A Level can have a parent Level (same entity).

A Level can have one or many Product(s).

```
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="Product_Code", type="string", length=20)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="Level_ID", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $levelId;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Level", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Level_ID", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $level;

}
```

I don't know very well where is the problem. Usually, the products should be deleted first, then Level 1.1 and Level 1 last.

Level 1 doesn't have products but, maybe it tries to delete products with `level_id = 1100` (instead of 1101) ??

**The deletion works well without products.** When I delete a level which has children levels, all levels are deleted properly.

The `cascade={"persist", "remove"}` seems to not work on my Product collection (in Level Entity).

It is weird because I use a lot a entities and relations between them with array collections, etc, and I hadn't got this error before.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**

I found a solution but I think it's not the correct way to do this. I have to do the cascade deletion manually, in the controller :

```
/* browse children levels */
foreach ($level->getChildren() as $child) {

    /* browse the products within the child level */
    foreach ($child->getProducts() as $product) {
        $em->remove($product);    -- delete product
    }
}

$em->remove($level);     -- delete the level (delete also children levels)
$em->flush();           -- update database
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Are you sure, you have updated your DB schema (`doctrine:schema:update --force`)?

Comment: Yes, I can add/edit/delete my products, my table is updated properly... I found a solution, I have to do the cascade deletion "manually". It's too bad that it doesn't work "automatically" but that corrects my problem. I will edit my post.